# Using Doctrine Annotations for creating custom annotations fails

Tags: php, annotations

I'm trying to define and use custom annotations but I can't figure out the problem. The basis is doctrine/annotations and these are my own classes:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\Annotations\Annotation;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("PROPERTY")
 */
final class Type
{
    /**
     * @Required
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;
}

<?php
namespace MyCompany\Annotations;

use MyCompany\Annotations\Annotation as MYC;

class Person
{
    /**
     * @MYC\Type(name = "string")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @MYC\Type(name = "string")
     */
    private $lastName;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }
}
```

Now I want to read the annotations of all properties:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
use MyCompany\Annotations\Person;

$refClass = new ReflectionClass(Person::class);
$props = $refClass->getProperties();

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    $reader = new AnnotationReader();
    $annotationReader = new CachedReader(
        $reader, new ArrayCache()
    );
    $annotations = $annotationReader->getPropertyAnnotations(
        $prop
    );
    print_r($annotations);
}
```

If I run my test script, it fails with the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException' with message '[Semantical Error] The annotation "@MyCompany\Annotations\Annotation\Type" in property MyCompany\Annotations\Person::$firstName does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.'
```

What confuses me is the fact that the class name in the error message starts with a '@' character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to register the annotations (both yours and any internal ones you're using). The easiest way to do this is to pass the Composer autoloader directly to Doctrine's `registerLoader` method:

```
$loader = require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, "loadClass"]);
```

at the top of your test script.

This assumes that you're doing all of your autoloading through Composer but if not, there are methods available to register individual files or namespaces described here [in the manual](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/annotations.html#registering-annotations)

Comment: Perfect! That was the trick. Is there also a possibility to edit the composer.json to load the classes on "composer update" (maybe with a phing task) or is it only possible on top of an init application script?

Comment: @altralaser Nothing I know about, sorry. I think this has to be done at runtime. Any project I've worked with that's used annotations has just included the extra line after including the Composer autoloader.